# How to prepare a rpm for R ( programming language )

Tags: r, linux, redhat, rpm

I want to prepare a RPM package for R . Please note that i am not allowed to install the same directly but a process of building the same needs to be followed. My Questions are:-

1) I want that RPM should provide me latest R version 3.2.3. How do i prepare a rpm for a server that enables me to install different version of R.

2)My version info is Linux version 2.6.18-308.8.1el5 Red Hat 4.1.2-52 , its an x86_64 box. How does this helps in making an appropriate R ( programming language of version 3.2.3) RPM for this box ?

3) I see the box is Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.8 (Tikanga )is this also be taken into account to build an appropriate RPM ?

4) Is there something else that i need to take care of ?

Comment: Why do it yourself? https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/redhat/README

Comment: RHEL 5.8 is **very** out of date and (quite likely) insecure. A number of point releases after 5.8 have been released.

Comment: @spacedman So does this means rpm i prepare would be independent of my Red Hat release and what i need to do is follow point 4 in link you provided ?

Comment: @Etan yes i know but then thats what we work on as of now.

Comment: You can try to build  the package from the latest source with rpmbuild: https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/SRPMS/repoview/R.html